# No matching member function for call to 'push_back' error

Tags: c++, vector, composition

```
//fleet.h 
#include "ship.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#ifndef fleet_h
#define fleet_h
using namespace std;

class fleet
{
public:

//Add_ship and remove_ship method
bool add_ship(ship const &s);

private:
vector<ship*> ships;
};

//Add_ship method
bool fleet::add_ship(ship const & s){
    ships.push_back(&s); 
       return true;
}
#endif /* fleet_h */
```

The program gives me this error and I'm not sure what did I do wrong. ship objects are added to fleet via a method called add_ship, which takes a pointer to a ship.

```
No matching member function for call 'push_back'
```

Comment: What is `shipss`? Please provide [mcve].

Comment: And when editing your question to add the MCVE, also please include the *full* and *complete* error output, including any possible informational notes. Copy-pasted as text of course. The solution to your problem is most likely in the parts of the error you do no show us.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen shipps is a vector that has ship type, sorry I forgot to include the initilization of the shipps vector. Just updated.

Comment: On an unrelated note, don't define (implement) functions in header files. If you include the header files in multiple source files, then those function will be defined multiple times as well. Either make the functions `inline` or put the definitions (implementations) in a separate source file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is a small program for my school assignment and the professor told me that it's ok to implement in the same header file, as long as I don't implement in the class definition.

Comment: Are you sure that you understood your professor correctly? Putting the function definition in the class body is more correct than the way you did it. If he fluid mean it, I suppose he wanted you to use the `inline` keyword. Otherwise this is bad code.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler I wouldn't say _bad code_ (which I understand as incorrect code). There is nothing bad if you include your header into a single source only. _Bad practice_ or _may lead to linking problems_ is likely better wording. (Just wanted to clarify to prevent misunderstandings how C++ works here.)

Comment: @DanielLangr "bad code" is not a well defined term, unlike "invalid code" which is not mentioned in the comment. Making a header file that can't be included from more than one source file, is beyond a mere bad practice. Unlike most things that you'd label as "bad practice", it is ***practically*** impossible to use this header file correctly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
//Add_ship method bool     
fleet::add_ship(ship const & s)
{ 
    ships.push_back(&s); (No matching member function for call to 'push_back') 
    return true; 
}
```

The error is because of the declaration:

```
std::vector<ship*> ships;
```

The vector contains pointers to mutable ships, but the code passes a pointer to a const ship to `push_back`. You either need to store const pointers in the vector:

```
 std::vector<const ship*> ships;
```

Or pass a non const pointer to the push_back:

```
fleet::add_ship(ship & s)
{ 
    ships.push_back(&s); (No matching member function for call to 'push_back') 
    return true; 
}
```

Side note: move the above function to a cpp, move it to the body of the class, or declare/define it as inline, if you don't want to get linker errors.

Comment: This is the most C++ thing I have heard all month, lol!  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @heyitsalec
 Actually, C also has const. GCC with `void push_back(int *ship);
void AddShip(const int *ship) { push_back(ship); }` will give you a nasty warning ` warning: passing argument 1 of 'push_back' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]`